# Point is not showing on a right place in admin panel while using geodjango?

Tags: python, django, django-models, geodjango

I have taken my current location longitude and latitude from google Map. And when I'm adding an entry with that log/lat value. The pointer is not identifying the right place.
As you can see in the pictures below.
This is how I'm adding point in db.

```
Profile.objects.create(
                owner=obj.owner,
                name=obj.ground_name,
                phone_no=obj.phone_no,
                location=GEOSGeometry('POINT (31.520370 74.358749)', srid=4326),
                address=obj.address,
                state=obj.state,
                city=obj.city,
                country=obj.country
                )
```

on admin panel
[image]

on google map

[image]

Comment: Did you try to invert the coordinates?

`location=GEOSGeometry('POINT (74.358749 31.520370)', srid=4326),`

GEOSGeometry and GoogleMaps might not use the same order for latitude and longitude

Comment: yeah it worked but can revert them that way it coming from frontend ?location=GEOSGeometry('POINT (31.520370 74.358749)', srid=4326)